# asp.net core cookie authentication sliding expiration not working

Tags: authentication, cookies

I have configured a cookie authentication in asp.net core 2 application, 
here is the configuration in startup,cs file

```
 //1:
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options =>
        {
            //REF:https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/09/08/asp-net-core-2-0-cookie-authentication/
            //Cookie Authentication Options

            //Login View
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            //Logout Action
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
            //Controls how much time the cookie will remain valid from the point it is created. 
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            //Ticket Expiration :represents the expiration of the ticket NOT the cookie that contains the ticket.
            //an expired cookie will be ignored even if it is passed to the server after the browser should have purged it.
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            //Cookie Expiration
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            //override default name of cookie, which is .AspNetCore.Cookies
            options.Cookie.Name = "HDAPP1.0";
            //cookie can be accessed from client side scripts
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;


            //ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl"
        });

        //2:
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });

        //3:add app.UseAuthentication(); in Configure Method
```

The issue is that the sliding expiration not working and the application always signout in 10 minutes either you do a work on the web site or not.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: exactly the same problem for me using asp.net core 3.1